# MySQL root deleted or lost password?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords, localhost, root

I lost my root privileges on localhost/phpmyadmin and I don't know if I accidentally deleted root or if I lost my root password... :

**-** When I type "root" with no password on config.inc.php, I can access to localhost/phpmyadmin but I can't see my databases nor my privileges. I have nothing.

**-** When I type "root" with some possible passwords, they all fail. I tried every logins and passwords possibilties, I always get the #1045 error (password: "YES")

**-** In my console server (ubuntu via PuTTY), I can type `mysql -u root -p` and access to MySQL with a password...

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try using the username and password from debian.conf
You can look it up using

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Log in using commandline/putty

```
$ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p 

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Once logged in you can restore the privileges for that user.

Comment: Thanks! I can see a password. What can I do with it? I added it into config.inc.php with root user and still got "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" in localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: that is not the password for root, but for user debian-sys-maint . However, you should not use this for you phpmyadmin stuff, but just restore your root account.

Comment: The results: 
`mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)`

`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)`

Comment: But I still can't get root with all privileges. Please be aware that I am talking about localhost/phpmyadmin, not my server

Answer (score -1):

I run Debian 8. I was using the Debian Wiki to install the LAMP stack, and in the process lost track of my MySQL password, which prevented my logging in to phpmyadmin toward the end, to test my access. I spent most of an entire afternoon reading the experiences of others to get to a point of having access to my MySQL account through phpmyadmin. I seemingly exhausted all efforts and then it dawned on me that I might simply be able to uninstall mysql-client and mysql-server through

```
# aptitude remove mysql-client mysql-server
```

and then turning right around and reinstalling them. This worked, and by doing so I was able to reset my password, without losing track of it, and then use my new password to log in through phpmyadmin with username "root". Based on my reading, this username is applicable to all installations of mysql/phpmyadmin, so it should be the same username for anybody else using mysql/phpmyadmin. I am assuming at this point that non-root, or subordinate, users and usernames will in all probability be unique to the individual users of this software. Happy coding!

Comment: Would you really recommend to uninstalling the database server without recommending any kind of backup etc. before?